# Send PHP form via SMTP

Tags: php, smtp, contact-form

I've found some similar questions to my query, but none that fully match my situation.

I had a basic mail() PHP setup for use on the contact form on my website but, turns out this is blocked on my hosting server to avoid spam/abuse.

The web host recommends using SMTP as a workaround, but the tutorial they link to doesn't seem to provide a working solution for me!

This is my HTML:

```
<form action="php/mail.php" method="POST">
<p class="form-field-title">Name</p>
<input class="contact-field focus-hide" type="text" id="name" name="name" required autocomplete="off">
<p class="form-field-title">Email Address</p>
<input class="contact-field focus-hide" type="email" id="email" name="email" required autocomplete="off">
<p class="form-field-title">Phone</p>
<input class="contact-field focus-hide" type="text" id="number" name="number" autocomplete="off">
<p class="form-field-title">Message</p>
<textarea class="contact-field focus-hide" id="message" name="message" data-gramm_editor="false" required autocomplete="off"></textarea>
<input class="contact-button" type="submit" value="Send Message">
</form>
```

And this is my original (non-SMTP) mail.php code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$formcontent="Name: $name \nEmail: $email \nPhone Number: $number     \nMessage: $message";
$recipient = "email@email.com";
$subject = "Website Contact Form Enquiry";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

header('Location: ../thanks.html');
exit();
?>
```

I have the email server details for my web hosting, but none of the SMTP solutions I've found are working for me!

Is anyone able to help me? I've seen a few things about using PEAR, but their website doesn't seem to be working...?

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to use the native mail() function you will need to modify its config file which is never advised to do.The solution you want to use is a 3rd party mail library like phpMailer that will do all the heavy lifting for you. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 1):

If your form is in an email, I think you can't post data (maybe I'm wrong). But you can send it to your script with method get.

```
<form action="php/mail.php" method="GET">
</form>
```

Then update your php :

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$number = $_GET['number'];
$message = $_GET['message'];

$formcontent="Name: $name \nEmail: $email \nPhone Number: $number     \nMessage: $message";
$recipient = "email@email.com";
$subject = "Website Contact Form Enquiry";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

header('Location: ../thanks.html');
exit();
?>
```

It should do the job.